# Makefile command on mac OS shows incorrect output

Tags: linux, macos, makefile, gnu-make

I am new to Mac OS, and want to execute following makefile program.

```
GCCBASE = $(GCMDIR)/where/cplusplus/gcc
SRCS:=$(wildcard *.cpp) program.cpp
OBJS:=$(SRCS:.cpp=$(OBJDIR).o)
INCLUDES:=-I. -I$(ADD_INCLUDES)/Auto*.h -I$(ADD_INCLUDES)/program.h
OUTBASE =$(OUTBASE_EX)
OUT_ARTIFACT=Program

ifeq ($(OSNAME),Linux)
    ifeq ($(GFLIB_MODEL),64bit)
            CXXEXTRA_FLAGS = -m64
            GCCDIR = $(GCCBASE)/linux64/4.5.3
            GCCLIBDIR_W = $(GCCBASE)/linux64/4.5.3/lib64
            GCCLIBDIR = $(GCCLIBDIR_W)                
            CFLAGS_common += -I$(GCCBASE)/linux64/4.5.3/include
            OUTDIR = $(OUTBASE)/64
            CFLAGS_link_libs = -L$(GCCLIBDIR) -lmyLib                
    else
            CXXEXTRA_FLAGS = -m32
            GCCDIR = $(GCCBASE)/linux/4.5.3
            GCCLIBDIR_W = $(GCCBASE)/linux/4.5.3/lib
            GCCLIBDIR = $(GCCLIBDIR_W)
            CFLAGS_common += -I$(GCCBASE)/linux/4.5.3/include
            OUTDIR = $(OUTBASE)/32
    CFLAGS_link_libs = -L$(GCCLIBDIR) -lmyLib                
endif
endif
ifeq ($(OSNAME),Darwin)
echo "Mac OS"
    ifeq ($(GFLIB_MODEL),64bit)
            CXXEXTRA_FLAGS = -m64
            GCCDIR = $(GCCBASE)/macosx/4.8.1
            GCCLIBDIR_W = $(GCCBASE)/macosx/4.8.1/lib
            GCCLIBDIR = $(GCCLIBDIR_W)               
            CFLAGS_common += -I$(GCCBASE)/macosx/4.8.1/include
            OUTDIR = $(OUTBASE)/64
            CFLAGS_link_libs = -L$(GCCLIBDIR) -lmyLib                
    else
            CXXEXTRA_FLAGS = -m32
            GCCDIR = $(GCCBASE)/macosx/4.8.1
            GCCLIBDIR_W = $(GCCBASE)/macosx/4.8.1/lib/i386
            GCCLIBDIR = $(GCCLIBDIR_W)
            CFLAGS_common += -I$(GCCBASE)/macosx/4.8.1/include
            OUTDIR = $(OUTBASE)/32
    CFLAGS_link_libs = -L$(GCCLIBDIR) -lmyLib                
endif
endif
all: $(SRCS)
    echo "Building Program application..."
    $(CXX) $(CXXEXTRA_FLAGS) $(CFLAGS_common) $(INCLUDES) $^ -o $(OUTDIR)/$(OUT_ARTIFACT) $(CFLAGS_link_libs)        
    rm -f *.[o] *.log core
```

Command that gets executed on mac OS looks like this with linker errors since myLib was not found:

```
[exec] c++   -I. -IAuto*.h -IProgram.h Program.cpp -o /Program
```

While I am expecting my command to be like this:

```
[exec] c++ -m32 -I. -IAuto*.h -IProgram.h Program.cpp -o /Program -LmyPath -lmyLib
```

Why is my command not including -m32 and Linking library path?

I also tried printing CXXEXTRA_FLAGS and CFLAGS_link_libs, but they are empty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You never set the variables `OSNAME` or `GFLIB_MODEL` to any value in this makefile, so they're both empty.  Thus neither of the tests for `OSNAME` are true, and those values are never set in `CXXEXTRA_FLAGS` etc.

ETA: Here's an example based on your comments:

```
$ cat Makefile
ifeq ($(OSTYPE),Mac OS X)
   $(info got mac)
endif

all: ; @:

$ make

$ make OSTYPE=Mac

$ make OSTYPE='Mac OS X'
got mac
```

Comment: Thanks MadScintist: if OSNAME that I am passing is "Mac OS X" instead of "Darwin", how do I compare it in makefile. ifeq ($(OSNAME),Darwin) should be replaced with what?

Comment: Does the obvious `ifeq($(OSNAME),Mac OS X)` not work?

Comment: No it did not work for me, any change for space separated words, may be?

Comment: You're doing something wrong; it works fine.  However since we don't know what you're really doing we can't help.  Please update your question and show the actual setup you're using.